# How to merge two images in opencv?

Tags: visual-c++, image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, image-stitching

I have calculated homography ,taken out perspective transform .I am able two display two images in one window but unable to merge them.Here are my example images->
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

The code I am using thiscode ->

```
cv::warpPerspective(image2,warpresult2,homography,cv::Size(2*image2.cols,image2.rows));


Mat imgResult(image1.rows,2*image1.cols,image1.type());

Mat roiImgResult_Left = imgResult(Rect(0,0,image1.cols,image1.rows)); 
Mat roiImgResult_Right = imgResult(Rect(image1.cols,0,image2.cols,image2.rows)); 

Mat roiImg1 = image1(Rect(0,0,image1.cols,image1.rows));
Mat roiImg2 = warpresult2(Rect(0,0,image2.cols,image2.rows));

roiImg1.copyTo(roiImgResult_Left); //Img1 will be on the left of imgResult
roiImg2.copyTo(roiImgResult_Right); //Img2 will be on the right of imgResult

imshow("Finalimg",imgResult);
imwrite("C:\\OpenCv_Projects\\outputimage.jpg",imgResult);
cvWaitKey(0);
```

I think the problem is in the coordinates that i am giving roiImgResult_right.

And the Output Image is ->
[image: Output images]
As you can see the images are not properly merge and there is black area on the right side.how to remove that also?

Answer (score 17):

OpenCV already has image stitching implemented. If you compile with "-D BUILD_EXAMPLES", you can use the binary **stitching_detailed**. The usage is simple: `./stitching_detailed img1 img2 ...`

Or, you can just use the stitcher class (example from [here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/stitching.cpp?rev=6683)):

```cpp
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool try_use_gpu = false;
string result_name = "result.jpg";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector<Mat> imgs;
    // add images...

    Mat pano;
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
    stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);
    imwrite(result_name, pano);
}
```

Comment: I don't want to use stitching_detailed or  stitcher class .I want to code it as it's a part of project I am doing.Btw Thank You :)

Comment: I am getting an error -Can not open include file :'opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp': No such file or directory. How to remove this error.There is no file present as stitcher.hpp in my opencv folder.I am using opencv2.3.1.

Comment: In your opencv/modules directory, is there a stitching subdirectory? If not, you'll have to check out the svn repo to get a later version (the header is present in the [svn trunk](http://code.opencv.org/svn/opencv/trunk/opencv/modules/stitching/include/opencv2/stitching/stitcher.hpp)).

Comment: When i used the above code i get this : error C2248: 'cv::Stitcher::Stitcher' : cannot access private member declared in class 'cv::Stitcher'. How do i access the stitch function?

Comment: Stitcher::Stitch is public so you must be referring to something else. Maybe you are calling the private constructor.

Comment: The OpenCV stitcher assumes pure rotation (camera rotates around its axis) and if you introduce translation in your images the results are in most cases bad. However you can use the stitching in OpenCV as a guideline what you have to do - registration of your images (feature detection, feature matching, extracting camera parameters for each image etc.) and after that compositing (warping, seam removal and blending).Check the stitching pipeline in the documentation that has a nice overview of the whole thing and also read "Automatic Panoramic Image Stitching using Invariant Features" (see ref)

Comment: @rbaleksandar That's incorrect (saying OpenCV doesn't do that already, or the pure rotation assumption). Look at the source. https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stitching_detailed.cpp

Comment: I have looked at this, the source of the stitching-class and also the documentation and I do state that my comment is correct. Not only that you can see "Rotation model images stitcher" in the printUsage-function in this sample you gave me a link to (please do NOT confuse the terms rotation model (that is - motion model using rotation) with warp surface since these are two different things) but also if you try to test it (as I did), you will see the following: applying pure rotation on the camera gives great results but applying translation on the camera gives really bad ones.

Answer (score 7):

- ***Image Blending:*** You may use a laplacian pyramid [blending](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2010_spring/Lectures/blending.pdf). see a sample code [here](http://www.morethantechnical.com/2011/11/13/just-a-simple-laplacian-pyramid-blender-using-opencv-wcode/) using opencv. You can use whatever mask you like (which is a binary mask).
- ***create Panorama*** If you want to make a panorama, you may use Min-Cut Stitching. I
  found this code which do the panorama [processing](http://blog.blackhc.net/2010/07/panorama-stitching/).

Comment: What you are suggesting is next step.First I have to make sure that that the end image don't show  two mountain peaks instead of one.Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Image blending you can use if it is the same part of the mountain, if not use the bullet of create Panorama

Answer (score 2):

If you do more carefully, such as do not crop and stack, but use alphaBlend, then you will find something strange.

This is the matched image:

[image]

This is the wrapped img2:

[image]

This is the mask to do alphablend:

[image]

This is the alphaBlended:

[image]

---

We can easily find the ghost in the blended image. This is because the `warpPerspective` and `perspectiveTransform` can't really find the `real` camera projection equation. Mostly because the image panel is a `panel`, but a `cylindrical surface` or `spherical surface` or more complex. So the job we have done is not enough.

While the good new is `OpenCV` provides `High level stiching API`, We can do stitching easily by `OpenCV Stitching API`. Here is the result.

[image]

### Code:

```
//! 2018.01.16 14:43:26 CST
//! 2018.01.16 17:32:15 CST
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/stitching.hpp"
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

Stitcher::Status stitchImages(vector<Mat>&imgs,string fname, Stitcher::Mode mode = Stitcher::PANORAMA, bool try_gpu=false) {
    Ptr<Stitcher> stitcher = Stitcher::create(mode, try_gpu);
    Mat pano;
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher->stitch(imgs, pano);
    if (status != Stitcher::OK){
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << int(status) << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imwrite(fname, pano);
    return status;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    vector<string>fnames = {
        "img1.jpg", "img2.jpg"
    };

    vector<Mat> imgs;
    for(auto fname: fnames) {
        imgs.emplace_back(imread(fname));
    }
    stitchImages(imgs, "scans.png",Stitcher::SCANS );
    stitchImages(imgs, "pano.png",Stitcher::PANORAMA );
}
```

---

Some useful links:

1. OpenCV Stitching: https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/d8/d19/tutorial_stitcher.html
2. Alpha Blending in OpenCV C++ : [Combining 2 images with transparent mask in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216702/combining-2-images-with-transparent-mask-in-opencv/48275580#48275580)
3. Alpha Blending in OpenCV Python: 
   [Gradient mask blending in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594993/gradient-mask-blending-in-opencv-python/48274875#48274875)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily blend two images using the `addWeighted()` function.
But the requirement is that you have to make the images of the same size.

If the images are not of same size first resize the two images.
Then call the following function.

```
addWeighted(src1, alpha, src2, beta, 0.0, dst);
```

Declare the two `Mat` files

```
src1 = imread("c://test//blend1.jpg");
src2 = imread("c://test//blend2.jpg");
```

Also declare `alpha` and `beta` then save the result to `Mat dst`.

You can also get the details here [Blending of Images using Opencv](http://www.life2coding.com/blending-images-using-opencv/)