# Combining 2 images with transparent mask in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

What I'm basically trying to do is blur an image, and combine it back with the orignal, so that only certain areas in the original image are blurred (the face should be blurred).

My general idea was to mask the parts in the original Iwant to have blurred, then blur the original as a copy and "merge" them together again.

To a certain extend this also worked.

My images:

(1) Original
[image: Original]

(2) Original with parts that should be blurred
[image: Original with parts that should be blurred]

(3) Blurred
[image: Blurred]

My C++ code that creates these images:

```
int main(void) {
    cv::Mat srcImage = cv::imread(path);
    srcImage.convertTo(srcImage, CV_32FC3, 1.0/255.0);

    Mat _mask;
    Mat img_gray;

    cv::Scalar white = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);
    cv::Scalar black = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0);

    cv::cvtColor(srcImage, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    img_gray.convertTo(_mask, CV_32FC1);

    // face
    cv::circle(_mask, cv::Point(430, 350), 200, black, -1, 8, 0);

    // eyes
    cv::circle(_mask, cv::Point(502, 260), 27, white, -1, 8, 0);
    cv::circle(_mask, cv::Point(390, 260), 27, white, -1, 8, 0);

    // mouth
    cv::ellipse(_mask, cv::Point(440, 390), cv::Point(60, 25), 0, 0, 360, white, -1, 8, 0);
    cv::threshold(1.0-_mask, _mask, 0.9, 1.0, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);

    cv::GaussianBlur(_mask,_mask,Size(21,21),11.0);


    cv::Mat res;
    cv::Mat bg = Mat(srcImage.size(), CV_32FC3);
    bg = cv::Scalar(1.0, 1.0 ,1.0);

    vector<Mat> ch_img(3);
    vector<Mat> ch_bg(3);
    cv::split(srcImage, ch_img);
    cv::split(bg, ch_bg);

    ch_img[0] = ch_img[0].mul(_mask) + ch_bg[0].mul(1.0 - _mask);
    ch_img[1] = ch_img[1].mul(_mask) + ch_bg[1].mul(1.0 - _mask);
    ch_img[2] = ch_img[2].mul(_mask) + ch_bg[2].mul(1.0 - _mask);

    cv::merge(ch_img, res);
    cv::merge(ch_bg, bg);

    // original but with white mask
    res.convertTo(res, CV_8UC3, 255.0);
    imwrite("original_with_mask.jpg", res);


    // blur original image
    cv::Mat blurredImage;
    bilateralFilter(srcImage, blurredImage, 10, 20, 5);
    GaussianBlur(srcImage, blurredImage, Size(19, 19), 0, 0);

    blurredImage.convertTo(blurredImage, CV_8UC3, 255.0);
    imwrite("blurred.jpg", blurredImage);

    cv::Mat maskedImage;
    maskedImage = Mat(srcImage.size(), CV_32FC3);

    // now combine blurred image and original using mask
    // this fails
    cv::bitwise_and(blurredImage, _mask, maskedImage);
    cv::imwrite("masked.jpg", maskedImage);
}
```

My problem is that `cv::bitwise_and(blurredImage, _mask, maskedImage);` fails with

```
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and type), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array') in binary_op
```

Probably because `_mask` is a single channel image and `blurredImage` and `maskedImage` are 3-channel images.

How can I combine the images I got so that the currently white areas in image (2) are blurred using a transparent mask with "soft" edges?

Comment: should your mask be binary, or fading (e.g. the less white, the less blurred)?

Comment: @Micka faded, thats at least what I'm trying to achieve. It worked when using a binary mask in another example, but with that faded mask i ran in all kinds of problems, likely because my understanding of image processing is very basic.

Comment: just use a lineat combination : for each pixel: result = mask/255.0f * blurredpixel + (1-mask/255.0f) * originalpixel; if mask fades from 255 to 0

Comment: @Micka ok, is there any example you know of for this kind of transformation (website/article)? I think I understand it roughly, but an example would help a lot. So basically I create an new `Mat` and "copy over" the transformed pixels (for R/G/B/A)?

Comment: I don't have much time today, can you rrrmember me to create a small example on monday?

Comment: @Micka happy monday :) joking, but would be nice if you could provide some small example.

Comment: sorry, forgot about easter monday... will not have time until tomorrow :-(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of float conversion you can just use the linearcombination of byte channel values. See

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cv::Mat srcImage = cv::imread("C:/StackOverflow/Input/transparentMaskInput.jpg");

    //  blur whole image
    cv::Mat blurredImage;
    //cv::bilateralFilter(srcImage, blurredImage, 10, 20, 5); // use EITHER bilateral OR Gaússian filter
    cv::GaussianBlur(srcImage, blurredImage, cv::Size(19, 19), 0, 0);

    // create mask
    cv::Scalar white = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);
    cv::Scalar black = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0);

    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(srcImage.size(), CV_8UC1);

    // face
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(430, 350), 200, black, -1, 8, 0);

    // eyes
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(502, 260), 27, white, -1, 8, 0);
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(390, 260), 27, white, -1, 8, 0);

    // mouth
    cv::ellipse(mask, cv::Point(440, 390), cv::Point(60, 25), 0, 0, 360, white, -1, 8, 0);

    cv::GaussianBlur(mask, mask, cv::Size(21, 21), 11.0);

    // byte inversion:
    cv::Mat invertedMask = 255 - mask; // instead of inversion you could just draw the "face" black on a white background!


    cv::Mat outputImage = cv::Mat(srcImage.size(), srcImage.type());
    // for each pixel, merge blurred and original image regarding the blur-mask

    for (int y = 0; y < outputImage.rows; ++y)
    for (int x = 0; x < outputImage.cols; ++x)
    {
        cv::Vec3b pixelOrig = srcImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);
        cv::Vec3b pixelBlur = blurredImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x);
        float blurVal = invertedMask.at<unsigned char>(y, x)/255.0f; // value between 0 and 1: zero means 100% orig image, one means 100% blurry image
        cv::Vec3b pixelOut = blurVal * pixelBlur + (1.0f - blurVal)* pixelOrig;

        outputImage.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x) = pixelOut;
    }   

    cv::imshow("input", srcImage);
    cv::imshow("blurred", blurredImage);
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);
    cv::imshow("inverted mask", invertedMask);
    cv::imshow("output", outputImage);

    return 0;
}
```

using this input image:

[image]

computing this blurred and mask:

[image]

[image]

resulting in this output, by computing `(mask/255) * blur + (1-mask/255)*blur` (linear combination):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I define a function to do alphaBlend for two images of `CV_8UC3` with a mask of `CV_8UC1` in OpenCV:

```
//! 2018.01.16 13:54:39 CST
//! 2018.01.16 14:43:26 CST
void alphaBlend(Mat& img1, Mat&img2, Mat& mask, Mat& blended){
    // Blend img1 and img2 (of CV_8UC3) with mask (CV_8UC1)
    assert(img1.size() == img2.size() && img1.size() == mask.size());
    blended = cv::Mat(img1.size(), img1.type());
    for (int y = 0; y < blended.rows; ++y){
        for (int x = 0; x < blended.cols; ++x){
            float alpha = mask.at<unsigned char>(y, x)/255.0f;
            blended.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = alpha*img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) + (1-alpha)*img2.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, it's easy to do alpha bend on the images, just call `alphaBlend(...)`. Here is an example:

---

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

//! 2018.01.16 13:54:39 CST
//! 2018.01.16 14:43:26 CST
void alphaBlend(Mat& img1, Mat&img2, Mat& mask, Mat& blended){
    // Blend img1 and img2 (of CV_8UC3) with mask (CV_8UC1)
    assert(img1.size() == img2.size() && img1.size() == mask.size());
    blended = cv::Mat(img1.size(), img1.type());
    for (int y = 0; y < blended.rows; ++y){
        for (int x = 0; x < blended.cols; ++x){
            float alpha = mask.at<unsigned char>(y, x)/255.0f;
            blended.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) = alpha*img1.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x) + (1-alpha)*img2.at<cv::Vec3b>(y,x);
        }
    }
}

Mat createMask(Size sz){
    // create mask
    cv::Mat mask = cv::Mat::zeros(sz, CV_8UC1);
    // white and black
    cv::Scalar white = cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255);
    cv::Scalar black = cv::Scalar(0, 0, 0);
    // face
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(430, 350), 200, black, -1, 8, 0);
    // eyes
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(502, 260), 27, white, -1, 8, 0);
    cv::circle(mask, cv::Point(390, 260), 27, white, -1, 8, 0);

    // mouth
    cv::ellipse(mask, cv::Point(440, 390), cv::Point(60, 25), 0, 0, 360, white, -1, 8, 0);

    // Blur
    cv::GaussianBlur(mask, mask, cv::Size(21, 21), 11.0);
    return mask;
}

int main(){
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("img04.jpg");
    //  blur whole image
    cv::Mat blured;
    //cv::bilateralFilter(img, blured, 10, 20, 5); // use EITHER bilateral OR Gaússian filter
    cv::GaussianBlur(img, blured, cv::Size(19, 19), 0, 0);

    // Create the mask
    Mat mask = createMask(img.size());
    Mat mask_inv = 255 - mask;

    // Alpha blend
    Mat blended1, blended2;
    alphaBlend(img, blured, mask, blended1);
    alphaBlend(img, blured, mask_inv, blended2);

    // Display
    cv::imshow("source", img);
    cv::imshow("blured", blured);
    cv::imshow("mask", mask);
    cv::imshow("mask_inv", mask_inv);
    cv::imshow("blended1", blended1);
    cv::imshow("blended2", blended2);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Source:

[image]

Blured:

[image]

Mask1:

[image]

AlphaBlend 1:

[image]

Mask 2:

[image]

AlphaBlend 2:

[image]

---

---

Some useful links:

1. Alpha Blending in OpenCV C++ : [Combining 2 images with transparent mask in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216702/combining-2-images-with-transparent-mask-in-opencv/48275580#48275580)
2. Alpha Blending in OpenCV Python: 
   [Gradient mask blending in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594993/gradient-mask-blending-in-opencv-python/48274875#48274875)

Answer (score 0):

> Probably because _mask is a single channel image and blurredImage and
>   maskedImage are 3-channel images.

Put this before calling the `cv::bitwise_and`:

P.S if you do not want to alter your mask becuase you want to use it in another place just do it in a temporary variable:

```
cv::Mat _mask_temp;
cv::cvtColor(_mask,_mask_temp,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
cv::bitwise_and(blurredImage, _mask_temp, maskedImage);
_mask_temp.release(); // just in case you do not want it anymore to be in your memory(optional)
```

**EDIT (another problem):**

The mask is `32F` while the image is `8U`. So, you need this:

```
cv::cvtColor(_mask,_mask,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
_mask.convertTo(_mask, CV_8UC3);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but adding `cv::cvtColor(_mask,_mask,cv::COLOR_GRAY2BGR);` didn't change anything, same error.

Comment: your mask in 32F where your image is 8U just make the suitable conversation