# Gradient mask blending in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, mask

I have an image and circle zone. I need to blur all, except for circle zone. Also i need to make border of circle smooth.
The input:
[image: Input]

The output(made it in image redactor with mask, but i think opencv is using only bitmap masks):
[image: Output]

For now i have code in python, which isn't blurring border of circle.

```
def blur_image(cv_image, radius, center, gaussian_core, sigma_x):
    blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(cv_image, gaussian_core, sigma_x)
    h, w, d = cv_image.shape
# masks
    circle_mask = np.ones((h, w), cv_image.dtype)
    cv.circle(circle_mask, center, radius, (0, 0, 0), -1)
    circle_not_mask = np.zeros((h, w), cv_image.dtype)
    cv.circle(circle_not_mask, center, radius, (2, 2, 2), -1)
# Computing
    blur_around = cv.bitwise_and(blurred, blurred, mask=circle_mask)
    image_in_circle = cv.bitwise_and(cv_image, cv_image, mask=circle_not_mask)
    res = cv.bitwise_or(blur_around, image_in_circle)
    return res
```

Current version:
[image]
How can i blur the border of circle? In example of output i've used gradient mask in program. Is there something similar in opencv?
**UPDATE 04.03**
So, i've tried formula from [this answered topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216702/combining-2-images-with-transparent-mask-in-opencv) and what i have:
[image: Another try]
Code:

```
def blend_with_mask_matrix(src1, src2, mask):
    res = src2 * (1 - cv.divide(mask, 255.0)) + src1 * cv.divide(mask, 255.0)
return res
```

This code should work similar as recent one, but it doesn't. The image in circle is slightly different. It has some problems with color. **The question is still open.**

Comment: have a look at [THIS PAGE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30101044/how-to-blur-some-portion-of-image-in-android)

Comment: @Jeru I've already find a proper formula but have some issues with integreating it into python.  `(mask/255) * blur + (1-mask/255)*another img`. I'm trying to work without loops, only with built in numpy matrix operations

Comment: how well is your formula working?

Comment: @Jeru I got it from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216702/combining-2-images-with-transparent-mask-in-opencv). The main problem is that i cant divide matrix with mask on 255, because i'm getting assertation error `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (depth == CV_8U || depth == CV_16U || depth == CV_32F)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the main problem with `(mask/255) * blur + (1-mask/255)*another img` was operators. They were working only with one channel. Next problem is working with float numbers for "smoothing".
I've changed code of blending with alpha channel to this:
1) i'm taking every channel for source images and mask
2) Performing formula
3) Merging channels

```
def blend_with_mask_matrix(src1, src2, mask):
    res_channels = []
    for c in range(0, src1.shape[2]):
        a = src1[:, :, c]
        b = src2[:, :, c]
        m = mask[:, :, c]
        res = cv.add(
            cv.multiply(b, cv.divide(np.full_like(m, 255) - m, 255.0, dtype=cv.CV_32F), dtype=cv.CV_32F),
            cv.multiply(a, cv.divide(m, 255.0, dtype=cv.CV_32F), dtype=cv.CV_32F),
           dtype=cv.CV_8U)
        res_channels += [res]
    res = cv.merge(res_channels)
    return res
```

And as a gradient mask i'm just using blurred circle.

```
def blur_image(cv_image, radius, center, gaussian_core, sigma_x):
    blurred = cv.GaussianBlur(cv_image, gaussian_core, sigma_x)

    circle_not_mask = np.zeros_like(cv_image)
    cv.circle(circle_not_mask, center, radius, (255, 255, 255), -1)
#Smoothing borders
    cv.GaussianBlur(circle_not_mask, (101, 101), 111, dst=circle_not_mask)
# Computing
    res = blend_with_mask_matrix(cv_image, blurred, circle_not_mask)
    return res
```

Result:

[image: Result]
It is working a bit slower than very first version without smoother borders, but it's ok.
**Closing question.**

Answer (score 12):

I think maybe you want something like that.

This is the **source image**:

[image]

The **source-blured-pair** :
[image]

The **mask-alphablened-pair**:

[image]

---

**The code with description in the code comment.**

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# 2018.01.16 13:07:05 CST
# 2018.01.16 13:54:39 CST
import cv2
import numpy as np

def alphaBlend(img1, img2, mask):
    """ alphaBlend img1 and img 2 (of CV_8UC3) with mask (CV_8UC1 or CV_8UC3)
    """
    if mask.ndim==3 and mask.shape[-1] == 3:
        alpha = mask/255.0
    else:
        alpha = cv2.cvtColor(mask, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)/255.0
    blended = cv2.convertScaleAbs(img1*(1-alpha) + img2*alpha)
    return blended

img = cv2.imread("test.png")

H,W = img.shape[:2]
mask = np.zeros((H,W), np.uint8)
cv2.circle(mask, (325, 350), 40, (255,255,255), -1, cv2.LINE_AA)
mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (21,21),11 )

blured = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (21,21), 11)

blended1 = alphaBlend(img, blured, mask)
blended2 = alphaBlend(img, blured, 255- mask)

cv2.imshow("blened1", blended1);
cv2.imshow("blened2", blended2);
cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

Some useful links:

1. Alpha Blending in OpenCV C++ : [Combining 2 images with transparent mask in opencv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36216702/combining-2-images-with-transparent-mask-in-opencv/48275580#48275580)
2. Alpha Blending in OpenCV Python: 
   [Gradient mask blending in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594993/gradient-mask-blending-in-opencv-python/48274875#48274875)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mask upon an image using the following funciton:

```
def transparentOverlay(src, overlay, pos=(0, 0), scale=1):
    overlay = cv2.resize(overlay, (0, 0), fx=scale, fy=scale)
    h, w, _ = overlay.shape  # Size of foreground
    rows, cols, _ = src.shape  # Size of background Image
    y, x = pos[0], pos[1]  # Position of foreground/overlay image

    # loop over all pixels and apply the blending equation
    for i in range(h):
        for j in range(w):
            if x + i >= rows or y + j >= cols:
                continue
            alpha = float(overlay[i][j][3] / 255.0)  # read the alpha channel
            src[x + i][y + j] = alpha * overlay[i][j][:3] + (1 - alpha) * src[x + i][y + j]
    return src
```

You need to pass the source image, then the overlay mask and position where you want to set the mask.
You can even set the masking scale. by calling it like this way.

```
transparentOverlay(face_cigar_roi_color,cigar,(int(w/2),int(sh_cigar/2)))
```

For details you can look at this link: [Face masking and Overlay using OpenCV python](http://www.life2coding.com/python-opencv-based-face-masking-tutorial/)

Output:

[image: Face Masking Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a function from PIL library.
example -

```
from PIL import Image, ImageFilter
blur_factor = 3 # for smooth borders as you have mentioned

blurred_mask = mask.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(blur_factor)) # your circle = 255, background = 0
final_img = Image.composite(blurred_img, original_img, blurred_mask) # here blurred image is the one which you have already blurred, original image is your sharp non blurred image
```