# Add two images with blended edges

Tags: python, opencv

I'm writing a script to detect faces and blur out everything *but* the face.

I find the faces using Haar Cascades, then create a mask for with circles where the faces are. Then I add them together. This works fine for adding where the divide is absolute but I can't work out how to have the blur taper off without a blunt line. Blurring the mask just creates an ugly line where the tapering should be.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

original_image = cv2.imread('person.jpg')
gray_original_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# mask
# detect faces and create mask
mask = np.full(
    (original_image.shape[0], original_image.shape[1], 1), 0, dtype=np.uint8)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray_original_image, 1.3, 5)
face_areas = []
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    face_areas.append(([x, y, w, h], original_image[y:y+h, x:x+w]))
    center = (x + w // 2, y + h // 2)
    radius = max(h, w) // 2
    cv2.circle(mask, center, radius, (255), -1)

# blur original image
kernel = np.ones((5, 5), np.float32) / 25
blurred_image = cv2.filter2D(original_image, -1, kernel)
# blur mask to get tapered edge
mask = cv2.filter2D(mask, -1, kernel)

# composite blurred and unblurred faces
mask_inverted = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)
background = cv2.bitwise_and(
    blurred_image, blurred_image, mask=mask_inverted)
foreground = cv2.bitwise_and(original_image, original_image, mask=mask)

composite = cv2.add(background, foreground)

cv2.imshow('composite', composite)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Original
[image]

Output from script
[image]

Desired result (no obvious line between blurred/non blurred)
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient mask blending in opencv python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594993/gradient-mask-blending-in-opencv-python)

Answer (score 0):

You did most of the job, instead of `cv2.mean`, which by the way does not work when I tried, simply do:

```
composite = (foreground + background)
```

and you would get:

[image]