# Blend two images for panorama

Tags: python, opencv, panoramas, photography

Given that we calculate the homography matrix (3x3 in size) between two images--how can we blend two images in a panorama?

[For example, look at this panorama w/o blending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWgJ4.jpg). How do we get rid of the seam between images using alpha blending or some other method?

Comment: http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean Blending ?
you can start with linear Blending or you can do more little complicated but
elegant by using laplacian Blending

Check this 
http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-463/2010_spring/Lectures/blending.pdf

also this question might help 
[How to merge two images in opencv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256802/how-to-merge-two-images-in-opencv)

of course you can use the opencv stitcher which will do everything for you instead starting from the images